# PHP code for running "being watched" videos from selected category

Tags: php, wordpress

In this code videos are shown at random. I wanted to show them as selected category (i-e= 'links' category). How can I write this code to work for the links category?

```
<?php if( !defined('ABSPATH') ) exit; global $awpt; ?> 

<div class="being_watched">
  <div class="heading">
    <?php $h_tag = $awpt['live_videos_heading']; $title = $awpt['beingwatched_title'];
      echo '<'.$h_tag.'>'.$title.'</'.$h_tag.'>' ?>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <ul class="Thumbnail_List">
        <?php
          $per_page = $awpt['watched_now_videos'];
          query_posts('showposts='.$per_page.'&orderby=rand');
          if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php do_action( 'bestia_thumbnail_compatibility' ); ?>
        <?php endwhile; else: endif; ?>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `query_posts('showposts='.$per_page.'&orderby=category');` ??

Comment: Hi Asif, welcome to StackOverflow! This question needs a lot more context for people to be able to answer it easily. What part of the code shows the videos? How do you expect it to work? Could you also format the indentation?

Comment: Thanks RamRaider but this is for all categories, how about a selected category like i have 'links' category?

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply Timofy, i have video tube site where home page is divided into three portions; Being watched Videos, Latest Videos and Latest Photos.
so i want this being watched videos portion to show selected category instead of random videos as RamRaider points out the code.